# Is there a tool to backup files as soon as they are changed in or under specified folders on Windows?

Tags: windows, backup

Windows has a feature called *change notifications* which can inform a particular program when files in a particular directory tree are changed, such as by editing. I believe that Dropbox uses this feature to trigger synchronization.

Is there a tool that can make use of this feature by copying changed files in **any specified directory** to **any specific destination directory** instantly when they have been changed?

All the usual backup tools, such as Dropbox, Windows File History, and commercial backup programs **do not work exactly like this**.

Comment: If the windows change notifier can really call any program, why not learn a little bit of batch file scripting or whatever windows supports (I'm a linux guy `/bin/bash` forever!) and write a simple script.

Comment: Information on using PowerShell to track directory changes is at https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/09/24/changes-to-a-folder-using-powershell.aspx . I will answer here if I have time to create a tool that works.